# Embedded SWT Groups not filling all horizontal space

Tags: java, swt

I have an SWT Group which has two embedded Groups. Only one of them is visible at a time, and we can switch between them with a button.
The problem is, I want both to fill the whole space when they are visible, but they fail to do so.

```
package guitables;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ExpandBar;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ExpandItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class GuiTables {

    private static Group uIWrapperGroup;
    private static Group uGroup;
    private static Group iPGroup;
    private static ExpandBar expandBar;
    private static ExpandItem expandItem;
    private static Button switchToUButton;
    private static Button switchToIButton;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        create(shell);
    }
     
     private static void create(final Shell shell) {
        expandBar = new ExpandBar(shell, SWT.NONE);
        expandItem = new ExpandItem(expandBar, SWT.NONE);
        expandItem.setExpanded(true);
        uIWrapperGroup = new Group(shell, SWT.VERTICAL);
        uIWrapperGroup.setText("");
        uIWrapperGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(21, false));
        uIWrapperGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

        uGroup = new Group(uIWrapperGroup, SWT.NONE);
        uGroup.setText("");
        uGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(21, false));
        
        createUButtons(uGroup);

        iPGroup = new Group(uIWrapperGroup, SWT.NONE);
        iPGroup.setText("");
        iPGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(21, false));
        iPGroup.setVisible(false);
        
        createIPButtons(iPGroup);
    }

        private static void createUButtons(Composite parent) {
            switchToIButton = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);;
            switchToIButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    switchToIP();
                }

            });
        }
        
        private static void createIPButtons(Composite parent) {
            switchToUButton = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
            switchToUButton.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                    switchToU();
                }
            });
        }

        private static void switchToIP() {
            uGroup.setVisible(false);
            GridData invisible = new GridData(0,0);
            invisible.exclude = true;
            uGroup.setLayoutData(invisible);
            uGroup.setVisible(false);
            GridData visible = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
            visible.exclude=false;
            iPGroup.setLayoutData(visible);
            iPGroup.setVisible(true);
            reLayoutExpandItem(expandItem, uIWrapperGroup, SWT.DEFAULT);
        }
        
        private static void switchToU() {
            iPGroup.setVisible(false);
            GridData invisible = new GridData(0,0);
            invisible.exclude = true;
            iPGroup.setLayoutData(invisible);
            iPGroup.setVisible(false);
            GridData visible = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
            visible.exclude=false;
            uGroup.setLayoutData(visible);
            uGroup.setVisible(true);
            reLayoutExpandItem(expandItem, uIWrapperGroup, SWT.DEFAULT);
        }

        public static void reLayoutExpandItem(ExpandItem expandItem, Composite composite, int maxHeight) {
            if (!composite.isDisposed()) {
                int height = composite.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT).y;
                if(SWT.DEFAULT != maxHeight && height > maxHeight) {
                    expandItem.setHeight(maxHeight);
                } else {
                    expandItem.setHeight(height);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Everything works, except the two embedded groups don't fill the available space horizontally, but end up being oriented to the left, and stopping way before the end of available space in the right. When there is only one embedded group, it fills the whole space the way I want it.
Whan can I look into?

Comment: Probably you need to use `GridData.exclude` but since you haven't provided a proper [mre] to test I can't be sure

Comment: I added some more code to make it more reproducible.

Comment: If you change the `exclude` value on something or change the GridData you must call `layout(true)` on the parent Composite to get it actioned

Comment: I added it, but still nothing changed.

Comment: That code doesn't compile.

Comment: The static keywords were missing, I added them.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

```
 void create(final Composite parent) {
      expandBar = new ExpandBar(parent, SWT.NONE);
      expandItem = new ExpandItem(expandBar, SWT.NONE);
      expandItem.setExpanded(true);

      uIWrapperGroup = new Group(parent, SWT.VERTICAL);
      uIWrapperGroup.setText("Wrapper Group");
      uIWrapperGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout());
      uIWrapperGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

      uGroup = new Group(uIWrapperGroup, SWT.NONE);
      uGroup.setText("U Group");

      uGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(21, false));

      uGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false)); 

      createUButtons(uGroup);

      iPGroup = new Group(uIWrapperGroup, SWT.NONE);
      iPGroup.setText("I Group");

      iPGroup.setLayout(new GridLayout(21, false));

      iPGroup.setVisible(false);

      iPGroup.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false)); 
      ((GridData)iPGroup.getLayoutData()).exclude = true;

      createIPButtons(iPGroup);
   }

     private void switchToIP() {
          uGroup.setVisible(false);
          ((GridData)uGroup.getLayoutData()).exclude = true;

          iPGroup.setVisible(true);
          ((GridData)iPGroup.getLayoutData()).exclude = false;

          uIWrapperGroup.layout(true);

          reLayoutExpandItem(expandItem, uIWrapperGroup, SWT.DEFAULT);
      }

      private void switchToU() {
        uGroup.setVisible(true);
        ((GridData)uGroup.getLayoutData()).exclude = false;

        iPGroup.setVisible(false);
        ((GridData)iPGroup.getLayoutData()).exclude = true;

        uIWrapperGroup.layout(true);

        reLayoutExpandItem(expandItem, uIWrapperGroup, SWT.DEFAULT);
      }
```

This sets `GridData` on the groups when they are created with the correct `exclude` settings. The switch methods modify the existing GridData

Comment: Thank you for looking into it! This fixes the problem for one of the tables, but not the other, I keep trying based on this.

Comment: The problem is, I have to specify the number of columns for the two groups' GridLayouts because I have buttons above them that I didn't include here for brevity's sake.

Comment: Setting columns for the groups makes no difference. You do not want columns on the   `uIWrapperGroup` though as that will force space on the right. I have updated the code example above